# can't submit a form on express/angular app

Tags: javascript, node.js, angularjs, express

in my program there's a validation function on it, if there's an error it will prevent the form to submit and display error msg else it will `console.log("Success")` but my form cannot be submitted even without any error. is there anyway to enable status code `200` when there is no error ? because now the form prevent me to submit because of status code `400`

### express

```
function validateSignup(data,callback) {
        "use strict";
        var USER_RE = /^[a-zA-Z0-9_-]{2,25}$/;
        var PASS_RE = /^.{6,100}$/;
        var EMAIL_RE = /^[\S]+@[\S]+\.[\S]+$/;

        if (!USER_RE.test(data.publicUsername)) {
            callback(new Error('Invalid Public Username try just letters and numbers, e.g: Ed, 69, Kelvin and etc'), null);

        }
        if (!PASS_RE.test(data.password)) {
            callback(new Error('Password must be at least 6 characters long'), null);

        }
        if (data.password != data.confirmPassword) {
            callback(new Error('Password must match'), null);

        }
        if (!EMAIL_RE.test(data.email)) {
            callback(new Error('Invalid email address'), null);

            }
         if (data.email != data.confirmEmail) {
            callback(new Error('Email must match'), null);

        }
        return true;
    }
```

**handlesignup**

```
this.handleSignup = function(req, res, next) {
        "use strict";
    validateSignup(req.body, function(error, data) {
        if(error) {
            res.send(400, error.message);
        } else {
            console.log("success");
        }
    })
    }
```

### Angular

```
function RegisterCtrl($scope, $http, $location) {
    $scope.form = {};
    $scope.errorMessage = '';
  $scope.submitPost = function() {
    $http.post('/register', $scope.form).
      success(function(data) {
        $location.path('/');
      }).error(function(err) {
        $scope.errorMessage = err;
      });
  };
}
```

Comment: but when i change it to 200 it can redirect to location.path('/'); , but of course without the validation function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have multiple issues in your code.

1. Your `validateSignup` function doesn't always call its callback. If the input passes the validation, it shouldn't return `true` but instead call its callback with no error and the data:

   ```
   function validateSignup(data,callback) {
     // ...
     callback(null, data);
   }
   ```
2. You don't always answer the client's request:

   ```
   validateSignup(req.body, function(error, data) {
      if(error) {
          res.send(400, error.message);
      } else {
          console.log("success");
          res.send(200);
      }
   })
   ```

*Edit:* As a side note, a callback should aways be called asynchronously (ie. using `process.setImmediate`, `process.nextTick` or `setTimeout`), but that isn't an issue in your specific case as the callback will **always** be called synchronously. As noted in *Effective JS*, item 67:

> Never call an asynchronous callback synchronously, even if the data is immediately available.

That's why my advice is to always call callbacks asynchronously, which will free you from weird bugs later on. There are a number of reasons as why you shouldn't do it, but the most obvious is that you can easily blow the stack.

Here's how you you can defer the callback execution:

```
function validateSignup(data,callback) {
  // ...
  process.setImmediate(function() {
    callback(null, data);
  });
}
```

Comment: Hi, your answer works ! thank you so much , mind to elaborate about the side note or give me an example about it, i don't really get it, how can i use setTimeout to call callback ?

Comment: do i need to install any node module to perform process.setImmediate ? because i keep getting TypeError: Object #<process> has no method 'setImmediate'

Comment: You at least need Node v0.10. Another possibility is to use `process.nextTick()`.